# Plotly legend marker opacity and spacing

Tags: python, plotly, legend, marker, spacing

Is it possible to access the symbols in a legend? I would like to set their opacity to a higher value than the opacity of my trace markers, and ideally I would like to make them tighter (in the sense of a smaller gap between each row of the entry).

My code is fairly long and convoluted as it stands, and I don’t know if this question needs code as it’s essentially a general question about object attributes - please let me know if that’s wrong!

Cheers,
Tim